# Sort JSON object by custom Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, sorting

I have JSON object, which I want to sort it in certain way,

This is my object

```
{ "you": 100, "me": 75, "foo": 116, "bar": 15 }
```

And I want this object to be sorted in this order `['me', 'foo', 'you', 'bar']` which the object would become like this,

```
{ "me": 75, "foo": 116, "you": 100, "bar": 15 }
```

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Comment: Object properties have no ordering. You can extract the keys with `Object.keys()`, sort that array, and then use the array to get property values in some particular order.

Comment: If you already have an order defined with `['me', 'foo', 'you', 'bar']`, then why do you need to sort the object also? You can always fetch the properties in the order of the array you have defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a new object by iterating the given array with the keys.

More about order of objects: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

```js
var object = { you: 100, me: 75, foo: 116, bar: 15 },
    result = Object.assign(...['me', 'foo', 'you', 'bar'].map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will be messed up a property name is numeric.. `var object = { you: 100, me: 75, foo: 116, bar: 15, 1 : 23, "2" : 2 },
    result = Object.assign(...['me', 'foo', 'you', 'bar', "2"].map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] })));

console.log(result);`

Comment: @gurvinder372, the order is defined by keys who are possible to parse as integer are sorted first by value and then comes the rest with in insertation order. you may have a look into newer ecmascript standard.